# Objective-C: How to create a Menu with custom UI?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm trying to develop an application in Xcode 4.1. I would like to create an application located in the menu bar, like described in this tutorial:
http://cocoatutorial.grapewave.com/2010/01/creating-a-status-bar-application/

But instead of showing a standard Menu when clicking, I would like to show a more graphical UI with some text fields, buttons, etc. like they do in Fantastical:
http://flexibits.com/fantastical

I hope someone can tell me, how I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [*Status Bar Programming Topics*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/StatusBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000073i) guide.

1. Make an `NSStatusItem`.  Set the item's view to a custom view that you create.  This view will appear in the status bar and receive mouse clicks.
2. Make your custom view handle a mouse click by presenting a window with your custom UI.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use a custom view. All you have to do is set the status item's target & action to your method which shows the window:

```
[self.statusItem setTarget:self];
[self.statusItem setAction:@selector(ShowOrHideWindow:)];
```